# How do I use a row count in an @if in a Laravel view?

Tags: laravel

I am brand new to Laravel and I'm running Version 6.

I want my view to display a button if one of my MySQL tables has rows that meet a specific condition but I'm having trouble figuring out how to code it - and even WHERE to code it - within my Laravel application.

My MySQL table is called diary_entries and various users of the system will contribute zero to n  rows to it. Each row of the table contains a user id called client. When a given user goes to the Welcome view, I want the view to determine if that user currently has any rows in the diary_entries table. If he does, I want to display a button that will take him to another page where the entries can be displayed or edited or deleted.

I *think* I want to construct an @if that counts the number of records for that user; if the count is greater than zero, I want to display the button, otherwise the button is not displayed.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to code this. I've looked at the examples in the Eloquent section of the manual but they aren't particularly clear to me. I found a note near the top that said the count() function expects a Collection as an argument and that the result of an Eloquent statement is always a Collection so I guessed that I just have to execute an Eloquent query, then apply count() to the resulting Collection. But every variation of that idea which I've tried has thrown exceptions.

Here was the guess that seemed most logical to me:

```
@extends('layout');

@section('content');
<div class="content">
    <img class="centered" src="/images/sleeping-cat.jpg" alt="sleeping cat" height="250">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        <h1> Sleep Diary </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>{{Auth::user()->name }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        @if (count(App\DiaryEntry::select('*')->where('client', Auth::user()->name) > 0))
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary"> View / edit existing sleep diary entries </a>
            </p>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/diaryEntries"> Create a new sleep diary entry </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is obviously wrong because it throws an exception so how do I make it right? Does the building of the collection have to move into the Controller? If so, how do I invoke the method and see its result? Or can I do something like I have already done but just adjust the syntax a bit?

EDIT

I've imitated Sehdev's suggestion but I get this error:

```
$count is undefined

Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $count }} with {{ $count ?? '' }}
```

Here is my welcome view:

```
 @extends('layout');

 @section('content');
   <div class="content">
    <img class="centered" src="/images/sleeping-cat.jpg" alt="sleeping cat" height="250">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        <h1>Sleep Diary</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        @if ($count) > 0)) 
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">View/edit existing sleep diary entries</a>
        </p>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/diaryEntries">Create a new sleep diary entry</a>      
    </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

And this is the relevant function from DiaryEntryController:

```
 public function countEntriesOneUser()
 {
    $count = DiaryEntry::select('*')->where('client', Auth::user()->name)->count();
     view("welcome", compact("count"));
    }
```

Should the compact function be returning $count instead of count? I can't find the compact function in the manual with the search function so I'm not clear what it does or what the proper syntax is. I just tried changing the last line of the function to

```
view("welcome", $count);
```

but that produced the same error.

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application

Comment: blade template  shouldn't contain these **`App\DiaryEntry::select('*')->where('client', Auth::user()->name`**. Its a bad practice.

Comment: Please complete your question by adding the exception. People will be able to fix the problem faster if they could see the error.

Comment: I think you have used different functions for show `welcome` blade and that is why count undefined.
Because of laravel installation give default route for shows `welcome` blade. Use different blade file for testing and check it work or not.

Comment: Laravel default route in web.php. `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`

Comment: @manpreet - I don't see how this article answers my specific question but it is very helpful in other regards. Thank you!

Comment: @Abdulla - I accept that this may be bad practice but WHY is it a problem?

Comment: @Henry, Thanks, as you are new to Laravel, this tutorial will help you with understanding what goes where, as everyone has pointed that query must not be in blade. It may be in Controller, as the result be passed to view using a variable. You can then have if count on that variable. Your query will also run only once. This is for Laravel 5.2 but will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#displaying-existing-tasks , you can let go Repositories for now. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#displaying-the-tasks has if count example

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@php
$count=\App\DiaryEntry::where('client', Auth::user()->name)->count();
@endphp
@if($count>1)
 <p><a class="btn btn-primary">View/edit existing sleep diary entries</a></p>
@endif
```

Comment: No explanation !

Comment: This is bad practice. You should never have your eloquent queries in your blade files

Answer (score 0):

Using `App\DiaryEntry::select('*')->where('client', Auth::user()->name)` directly on your blade template is a bad practise.

You can execute your question in your controllers method and then pass the result on your view file

> Your function

```
function test(){

    $count = DiaryEntry::select('*')->where('client', Auth::user()->name)->count();  // get the total no of records using count
    view("index", compact("count")) // pass your count variable here

}
```

then you can directly use `$count` in your `@if` condition

> Your blade template

```
<div>
    @if ($count > 0)
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary">View/edit existing sleep diary entries</a></p>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I like your suggestion and tried it but it didn't work. It complains that $count is undefined in the welcome view. I created the function in my Controller and gave it a better name - countEntriesOneUser() - and changed the view name in the second line to welcome, which is the view where I'm going to use the $count. Everything else is identical to your suggestion.

Comment: @Henry I tied the same code and it is working fine at my end. Please share your code that you have tried